# Java referencing to single ArrayList instance

Tags: java, object, collections, arraylist, foreach

I have encountered a problem with the ArrayList I'm using. This is a list of objects containing sprites with a color and location that differ from each other. The list is returned successfully and I can use a foreach loop to draw them all to the screen. After that I am checking if someone has clicked on their location and I want to return the color that the object contains. The problem is I always get the color green back. Probably because I reference to all the objects instead of a single one. I have searched through this site and found similar problems and tutorials. But I can not seem to find the information I need to fix the code so that I can reference to a single instance in the list while using a foreach loop to check them all.

After reading the answers and using break and the forgotten secondColor = true, I still have the same problem. Even when sending the clicked object to another function my problem is not solved. So instead of only showing the code for reading out the list I show the code for when the list is filled as well. How can I fix that I only refer to the green object at all times when reading the list but when using the for loop to draw I get every color????

```
for(KleurWissel i : gameManager.getColorsList())
        {
            i.colorRectangle.draw(batch);
        }
        //Welke kleuren kies je?
        if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){
            Iterator<KleurWissel> iterator = gameManager.getColorsList().iterator(); 
            while(iterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                KleurWissel item = (KleurWissel) iterator.next();

                if(item.getRectangle().contains(input.x, input.y)) 
                { 
                    if(firstColor == true && secondColor == false && item.selected == false)
                    {
                        colorArraySecond = item.colorArray;
                        colorArrayUsed = colorArrayFirst;
                        colorSelected = true;
                        item.selected = true;
                        secondColor = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(firstColor == false && item.selected == false){
                        colorArrayFirst = item.colorArray;
                        firstColor = true;
                        item.selected = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
```

And here the code for filling the list.

```
private int[] colorsRGB = {0, 50, 150, 150, 200, 255};
float[] colorArrayUsed = new float[4];
private ArrayList<KleurWissel> colorsList = new ArrayList<KleurWissel>();


public void setColorsList()
{
    Vector2 tempV;
    KleurWissel temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if(i<3)
        {
            colorArrayUsed[0] = colorsRGB[5-i];
            colorArrayUsed[1] = colorsRGB[0+i];
            colorArrayUsed[2] = 0;
            colorArrayUsed[3] = 1;
            tempV = new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - 150 + i * 150, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 + 130);
        }
        else{
            if(i == 3)
            {
                colorArrayUsed[0] = 0;
                colorArrayUsed[1] = 0;
                colorArrayUsed[2] = colorsRGB[5];
                colorArrayUsed[3] = 1;
                tempV = new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - 150, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
            }
            else{
                colorArrayUsed[0] = 0;
                colorArrayUsed[1] = colorsRGB[0+i];
                colorArrayUsed[2] = colorsRGB[5-i];
                colorArrayUsed[3] = 1;
                tempV = new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - 600 + i * 150, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
            }

        }
        temp = new KleurWissel(colorArrayUsed, tempV);

        colorsList.add(temp);
    }
}

public ArrayList<KleurWissel> getColorsList()
{
    return colorsList;
}
```

KleurWissel is the color object, sorry for the bit of Dutch >.>.

Comment: It's a huge mess. I'd advise you make local variables for the `Gdx.input.getY()` etc which you use in the loop. It'll be easier on eyes and also much more efficient.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not in the logic but in the traversing of the list ?

Comment: I suggest you run this code under debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on the comments:

The libGDX `Rectangle` class has a `contains` method, and it seems like this is what you are checking there manually. You could also print some information that tells you more about whether an object was hit or not.

It seems like the intended process is the following:

- When the first item is clicked, its color should be stored as `colorArrayFirst`
- When the second item is clicked, its color should be stored as `colorArraySecond`, and the `colorSelected` flag should be set to `true`

The followign code shows how this could be done. But the question still when this information will be "reset". That is, when will both arrays be reset to `null`, and when will the `colorSelected` flag be reset to `false`?

```
private boolean colorSelected = false;
private int colorArrayFirst[] = null;
private int colorArraySecond[] = null;

void someGameLoopMethod()
{
    if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT))
    {
        Iterator<ColorObject> iterator = gameManager.getColorsList().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            ColorObject item = (ColorObject) iterator.next();

            float x = Gdx.input.getX();
            float y = Gdx.input.getY();
            Rectangle r = item.colorRectangle;

            System.out.println("Check if "+x+" "+y+" is in "+r+": "+r.contains(x,y));

            if (r.contains(x,y))
            {
                clickedItem(item);
            }
        }
    }
}


private void clickedItem(ColorObject item)
{
    if (colorArrayFirst == null)
    {
        colorArrayFirst = item.colorArray;
    }
    else if (colorArraySecond == null)
    {
        colorArraySecond = item.colorArray;
        colorSelected = true;
    }
}

// TODO Think about when this method should be called
private void resetClickingInformation()
{
    colorSelected = false;
    colorArrayFirst = null;
    colorArraySecond = null;
}
```

Comment: First and second color are used to save the selected colors. After that the game begins and these colors are used to create two new objects. Also for obtaining the right colors to be able to paint.

Comment: Ow and thanks for the reply the contain method is far better than what I used before :D.

Comment: @Ano333333 OK, I still wonder why this could be accepted as an answer. If it somehow helped to resolve your problem, it would be great if you told us what the actual problem was. If it did **not** help to resolve the problem, you should not mark it as the "accepted" answer (only as "helpful", in the best case)

Comment: Sorry for that, misunderstood the purpose of the mark, the problem however persists as I can not obtain the color of the clicked object from the arraylist.

Comment: @Ano333333 Again, please explain (preferably by editing your original question) what the `firstColor` and `secondColor` flags are intended for and how they are used. Where are they set to `true` or to `false`? Is it right that you want to save to colors of (up to) **two** objects that are hit by one mouse click?

Comment: Okay the color vars are int[] arrays, which are used to save 4 integers per array, to be able to use them for the color of two objects. Where you fill the first array after clicking a color object and obtaining the second color after clicking the second object. After this you have chosen the colors which are used to create the two color objects that you can click for switching the current painting color. The only problem I am encountering now is that when I click an color object, is that I always get the color green which is the last object in the Arraylist for color objects.

Comment: To add, colorRectangle is the sprite of the object

Comment: @Ano333333 I edited the answer based on this comment. The intended process is still not entirely clear, but maybe the current sketch already comes close to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your original question is fine, except that you need to add either

```
secondColor = true;
break;
```

inside the block with `if(firstColor == true && secondColor == false)`.

If you don't do this, then after you set the second colour, you will keep iterating through the `ColorObject` objects, looking for more of them that include the point that was clicked, until eventually, you get to the last one - which presumably spans the whole canvas and has green as its colour.

The `break;` isn't strictly necessary, but it saves you from having redundant iterations.